# How to exclude patients in R based on number of readings?

Tags: r, dataframe, linear-regression

I'm struggling with a particular aspect of filtering my data.

I have a table that records about 300 parameters for about 8000 patients over the course of a study. I can already filter for those without baseline readings, but I'm struggling to exclude patients with a low number of readings for a certain variable.

For example, I'm trying to run a simple model which correlates a gastrointestinal score with a range of other variables. What I need to ensure is that patients with zero, or one reading for SCOPAAUT_gastrointestinal are excluded. Has anyone dealt with anything related to this? I can index for patient number, but from there, I'm unsure where to progress.

```
model1 <- lmer(SCOPAAUT_gastrointestinal~Age_bl + GENDER + EDUCYRS + APPRDX_enrol +
                 (1 + Years_bl|PATNO), data = datasetfilteredDR)
```

Comment: If you had a tiny snippet of some reproducible data you could surely be helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without reproducible data it is difficult to gauge what exactly you need. But from the post it seems you're simply trying to figure out how to filter a dataframe on a certain condition. That can be done by subsetting.

Let's assume you have a dataframe along these lines:

```
set.seed(23)
df <- data.frame(
  patient = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "B"),
  readings = c(sample(1:5, 10, replace = T)),
  other_var = c(sample(10))
)
df
   patient readings other_var
1        A        5         8
2        A        4         4
3        B        3         3
4        C        1         6
5        A        3         7
6        B        5         5
7        A        2         2
8        C        1         9
9        A        5         1
10       B        1        10
```

And let's assume you want to exclude those patients that have less than 3 readings. Then you can use the negation operator `!`and subset `df`on the variable on which you want to filter:

```
df_filtered <- df[!df$readings < 3, ]
df_filtered
  patient readings other_var
1       A        5         8
2       A        4         4
3       B        3         3
5       A        3         7
6       B        5         5
9       A        5         1
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried the solution and it didn't work. I don't think I was clear enough. For some patients, under a variable, there simply aren't more than two values. For each patient, I need to count how many values there are for that variable. If that number is 1 or 0, I need to exclude them from a subset.

Comment: Without you providing a glimpse of your data it will always be tricky to help. But if the problem is just the threshold then why not simply reduce it, e.g., like this: `df_filtered <- df[!df$readings <=1, ]`. That exludes patients that have fewer than or exactly 1 reading.